# I've got an issue with using 'visit'

Tags: cypress

When my Cypress tests are run on Github (headless).

When I call `visit('/page')` -  get a 404 error. The page definitely exists.

```
CypressError: 'cy.visit()' failed trying to load:

http://localhost:4200/page
```

I can run the same tests locally (headless and headed) and they work fine.

Anyone have any ideas why this could be?

I should add that this is an Angular Application and there are no 404's because all routes are handled with wildcard. I know this page exists and happens if i try to `visit` another page that exists.

[image]

Version:
`"cypress": "^10.6.0",`

This is the .yml file. The baseUrl is set to 'http://localhost:4200' in the 'integration.config.ts' file.
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the issue? Which Cypress version are you using? Which browser are you testing with it? Also, maybe you don't have installed the required browser?

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: I have the required browser as it all works until i use `visit` if i manually select links etc it works. only if i manually go to a page i get this error.

Comment: Also, I should add it works locally. It's only on github actions when I get these fails.

Comment: Are you positive that your application is running, and running at the specified port, in the pipeline?

Comment: If i do `cy.visit('/')` it works. So I assume it's running where expected. I'll add a screenshot of the  yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found the answer.

We are serving the Angular application with 'http-server'. It was only recognising the route '/' and was returning a 404 for any other app routes / pages.

We fixed this by adding `--proxy http://localhost:4200?` to the  `http-server` command.